# how to update sqlite using expression?

Tags: android, sqlite

I would like to do this query in SQLite:

```
  update table1 set col1 = (? || substr (col1, col2))
  where table1.id in (select id from table2 where condition);
```

I'm not sure how to do this.  SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery doesn't work.  All the other APIs I've seen don't allow the expression in the "set" part.  If I could use SQLiteStatement, it would work.  But that constructor is only visible in its package, not to my code :(

Ideally, I would do something like this:

```
String query = 
  "update Table1 set " +
  "  col1 = (? || substr (col1, col2)), " +
  "  col2 = ? " +
  "where Table1.id in " +
  "  (select id from Table2 where col3 = ?)";

String[] args = new String[3];
args[0] = arg0;
args[1] = arg1;
args[2] = arg2;

SQLiteStatement statement = new SQLiteStatement (getDb(), query, args);
int rowsUpdated = 0;
try
{
  rowsUpdated = statement.executeUpdateDelete();
} finally {
  statement.close();
}
```

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: Did you try with execSQL() ?

Comment: Maybe I missed that one.  I'm going to be out for a little while but will try it later tonight.  Thanks!

Comment: Yep, that works.  Go ahead and "answer" my question and I'll get you some points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when we want to run CRUD operations we use `SQLiteDatabase.execSQL()`.

`SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery()` is generally used for *select* queries and it returns a `Cursor` with the result set.

Although `rawQuery()` should theoretically work because according to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html)

> Runs the provided SQL and returns a Cursor over the result set.

But others have reported that it doesn't work with *update* queries, so I'm not entirely sure about that.